# Вик В(У)айльд

Tags: имена-собственные

Натурализованный американец  Vic Wild завоевал для России уже второе золото на олимпийских играх в Сочи. Его имя по российскому паспорту **Виктор Вайлд**, но подавляющее большинство новостей пишут его фамилию через "у", да и комментаторы произносят фамилию на английский манер. Чем вызвана такая тенденция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, по аналогии с писателем.
Поскольку английского звука, обозначаемого буквой W, в русском нет, возможны варианты его замены: У или В (например, в книге про Шерлока Холмса у меня был доктор Уотсон). В последнее время чаще встречается У.  Но если есть фиксация фамилии русскими буквами в российском паспорте, её и стоит придерживаться применительно к данному человеку. Я так думаю.

Answer (score 1):

Рассуждения дилетанта(я не учила английский):

В английском языке  согласная "w" произносится как  твёрдая "у". Когда пишут Уайлд (как и Уильям Шекспир)- это транслитерация, передача произношения языка-источника русскими буквами. Вайлд - верная графическая передача. Сейчас вроде все произносят  Вильям Шекспир - на русский манер, а когда-то только Уильям. Генрих Гейне тоже должен бы быть Хайнрих Хайне, но в русском языке закрепилось так.